# How to sum array along 3rd dimension

Tags: r, arrays, aggregate

What is the canonical way to sum a 3D array along dimension 3 (thereby yielding a matrix)?

I know I can `apply(A,c(1,2),sum)` but (wrongly or rightly) I got the impression from somewhere that using `apply` is no better than using `for` loops.

I could probably `aperm` the array, `colSum` it, then un`aperm` it again, but that wouldn't be very readable.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `rowSums`. It offers a `dims` parameter which specifies "[w]hich dimensions are regarded as ‘rows’ or ‘columns’ to sum over. For row*, the sum or mean is over dimensions dims+1".

```
a <- array(1:16, c(2, 2, 2))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    7
#[2,]    6    8

rowSums(a, dims = 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6   10
#[2,]    8   12
```